# Change img attribute and disable inputs with jQuery after PHP form validation

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-form-validator

I am trying to change the 'src' of an image element and also change the properties of input elements to 'readonly' after a form has been validated and submitted. The validation of the form occurs in PHP so I cannot attach an on submit event handler as it will trigger even if the form has not passed validation. Is there any way to do this without a plugin of some kind?

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
 </head>

 <body>

  <script> 
   $(document).ready(function() 
   {
      $("#button_img").click(function ()
      {
         alert("button clicked");
         $("#course_name").css("background-color", "yellow");
         $("#course_name").attr("readonly",true);
         $("#button_img").attr('src','../images/edit_course.png');
      });
   });    

  </script>

  <form id='design_course'  action="<?php ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
   <label id="course_name_label">Course Name:</label>
   <input type=text   id="course_name" name="course_design_name" value="default">
   <button  id="create_course" type="submit" ><img id="button_img" src="../images/create_course.png"></button>  
  </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your form will be submitted if you use `submit` button you need to use normal button instead of submit button as well as manually submit form using `$('#design_course').submit()`

Comment: or you could just add a hidden form field that you set AFTER the validation has been passed and BEFORE the form is submitted. After the submit you will check this hidden field for a certain value that indicates you will have to change the src and the other stuff

Comment: Is there any way to trigger a javascript function after the form has finished validation though?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what the intent is here.  You want to modify the page after it's been submitted?  So... The next time it loads?  If your validation logic is in PHP then you can conditionally output whatever HTML you want based on the result of that logic.

Comment: Do you want to use ajax to submit the form or you want to reload the whole page?

Comment: I only want the DOM to update and add a table when the validation has passed - would ajax be the bets approach here?

Comment: Yes, if you want to send the form, validate and get a response from the server without reloading the whole page you need to use ajax.

Comment: @jon: AJAX would certainly be *an* approach here.  Just a very different one from what you're already doing and from what you've asked in the question.  Either approach is fine, it's up to you how you want to architect your application.

Comment: @David if I'm not getting it wrong he wants to validate the form with php, so It can't be done without ajax or reloading, isn't it so? The other approach would be to validate the form using js.

Comment: @MarioZ: Correct.  And currently he's reloading the page, which is a perfectly valid approach.  He doesn't *have* to use AJAX if he doesn't want to, though he certainly can if he does want to.

Comment: @David Ok, I assumed that he didn't want to reload the page as the question states "with jQuery".

Comment: @MarioZ: And you may be onto something, as I suspect the OP isn't 100% aware of the implications of client-side vs. server-side logic.  He says he wants to "use jQuery", but also says the logic is server-side.  Is he implying that he wants to move to an AJAX approach?  That he wants to implement the validation logic client-side as well?  That he is just assuming "use jQuery" is some magic wand?  Something else?  We can guess (and we each have, hopefully helpful to the OP), but he should really clarify if we're off the mark here.

Comment: I don't know ajax yet so will be doing some tutorials on it - thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the validation logic you're using for this is server-side, the page is going to be changing during a reload.  So your logic for conditionally setting values in your HTML would be server-side.

You can conditionally output to the page from PHP based on any `if` statement.  You're not showing the validation logic, but let's assume for the sake of example that if validation passes then there is a boolean variable called `$passedValidation`.  Then you can do something like this in your code:

```
<?php if ($passedValidation) { ?>
    <img id="button_img" src="../images/something_else.png">
<?php } else { ?>
    <img id="button_img" src="../images/create_course.png">
<?php } ?>
```

So note that if the form "passed validation" then the image used is `something_else.png` instead of `create_course.png`.  So when the page reloads after having passed the validation logic, the user will see the other image.

The same can be done for other HTML output.  How you organize it is up to you, as it could get ugly to re-use this same `if/else` structure for a variety of attributes on the page.  Perhaps you can just have two complete forms wrapped in a single `if/else` block or something like that.

Note also that you'll want a default case of `false` for `$passedValidation` to handle when the page is first loaded and no form has been submitted at all.